# Fetching data from Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to fetch data from Firestore, when I console log it I got the content of my collection back, but when I move the code to a function I am not able to return it back.

This code works:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true});
db.collection('story').get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {console.log(doc.data())
    ;})
})
```

This doesnt work. (it compiles, but doesn`t return anything):

```
...
getMyStory = () => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true});
        db.collection('story').get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            let items = doc.data();
        })
        });
        return this.items;
    }


    render () {


        return (
        <p>{this.getMyStory}</p>
);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your rendering logic will need to account for the query to Firebase being asynchronous. Consider making use of your components `state` to resolve this, by making the following adjustments to your code:

```
getMyStory() { /* Remove arrow function */

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true});
    db.collection('story').get().then((snapshot) => {

      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          let items = doc.data();

          /* Make data suitable for rendering */
          items = JSON.stringify(items);

          /* Update the components state with query result */
          this.setState({ items : items }) 
      });

    });
}
```

Next, add `componentDidMount()` to your component, and then add the call to `getMyStory()` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {

    /* Cause your component to request data from Firebase when
       component first mounted */
    this.getMyStory()
}
```

Finall, update your render method to use the state, rather than method:

```
  render () {

    return (<p>{ this.state.items || 'Loading' }</p>);
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that too. Still doesn`t return anything.

Comment: Nope. :( It shows 'Loading' for a few secs and then 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {story}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Comment: @DacreDenny , As it converts the JSON object into string, then how can we reference particular field of the retrieved object while showing. Example `items.location`. This is not possible as we have stored plain string in the state using the `JSON.stringify()` function.

Comment: @DacreDenny, got the solution. It can be solved using `JSON.parse()`. correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of
>   an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value

Based in your code *return this.items;* executed first and then resolve *db.collection('story').get()*, finally never get the results.

Basically this line:

```
db.collection('story').get()
```

it's a promise then you must wait that resolve the result, below code:

```
getMyStory = () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true});

    return db.collection('story').get()
}
```

[Read More About Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

=======================EDIT=========================

```
getMyStory().then((snapshot) => {
    const listItems = snapshot.map((element) =>
      <li>{element}</li>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

[Read More About Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Same here as well. :/ "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: @GabriellaCsernus, please check out my answer! hope to help you

Comment: the code just an idea, in the case yet persist the issue, please post all code, for more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you are trying to render async data synchronously, which isn't possible to do with react [(not yet at least)](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

When rendering async data you will usually leverage component [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Below is a standard usage pattern when loading and rendering something async.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  }

  // This method is called when the component mounts
  // Usually  a good place to do async requests
  componentDidMount() {

    db.collection('story').get().then(snapshot => {
      // After promise is finished set data to local state
      // When setting state the render method will be called, thus rerendering the UI
      this.setState({ items: snapshot })
    })
  }

  render() {
    // Access your items from local component state
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {items.forEach(doc => {
          // Render whatever data is in your document
          return <p key={doc.id}> { Your data goes here }</p>
        })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "../config";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Reference firebase in this.state, creating a global key-value pair
    this.state = {
      roomsRef: firebase.firestore().collection("rooms"),
      rooms: []
    };
  }

  // Retrieve data from firebase and set state
  getDb(db) {
    db.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let room = doc.data();
        room.key = doc.id;
        this.setState({
          rooms: this.state.rooms.concat(room)
        });
      });
    });
  }

  // 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDb(this.state.roomsRef);
  }

  render() {
    const rooms = this.state.rooms.map((r, i) => <li key={i}>{r.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <section className="room-list">
          {this.state.rooms.length === 0 ? (
            <p>loading...</p>
          ) : (
            <ul>{rooms}</ul>
          )}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

if any one is using React with Redux with Firebase and has difficulty here is how to do it
here i get all the publications from firestore using redux

```
// publicationsActions.js

var publicationsRef = db.collection("publications")
var publicationsList = []

// Function that returns the publications list
export const getPublications = () => async (dispatch) => {
    await publicationsRef.get().then((res) => {
        res.docs.forEach(doc => {
            publicationsList.push(doc.data())
        })
        dispatch({
            type: GET_PUBS,
            payload: publicationsList
        })
    })
}


// publicationReducer.js

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_PUBS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            }
        case ADD_PUB:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: [action.payload, ...state.items]
            }
        default:
            return state; 
    }
}
```