# Firebase Get() not returning any docs

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot seem to get any docs from firebase in my react-native project.

This is the code:

```
async function GetUsers() {
    firebase.firestore()
        .collection("Users")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            console.log(querySnapshot);
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
                console.log(5);
            });
        });
}
```

The function is called in

```
componentDidMount() {
        GetUsers();
    }
```

But the console is never fired because the docs is always empty.

[Here's my Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A2Am.png)

The connection is definitely setup correctly because I can add docs.

[image: Here's the output querySnapshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try removing await before the collection retrieval and verify.

Comment: How do you call this? Can you show the context?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `await` in the same function call as `then()`, however the `get()` should still be getting executed anyway. Could you share some more code so we can check if there are other problems before this function call?

Comment: I've added a bit more code to the original post, it all runs pretty clean up until the .then()

Comment: I've removed the await but that doesnt seem to make any changes

Comment: Try to replace your `querySnapshot.forEach` to `querySnapshot.docs.forEach`, let me know what comes up, also, try to print your `querySnapshot` on console to check whether it is entering on the `.then()`

Comment: I've changed the code again (check edited post).
It's returning the querySnapshot but '5' is definitely never called

Comment: This is very strange, cause you code does seems to be correct, the only explaination for what is happening is that there are no users, which is not the case. Add this to your code: `if (!querySnapshot.hasData || querySnapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) { console.log("empty snapshot"); }` and if it does log the empty snapshot text, it will mean that there is something wrong while performing the `.get()`

Comment: Also take a look at this [accepted community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880387/fetching-data-from-firestore/52880460#52880460), it might be something applicable to your issue

Comment: @ralemos If added your code and it does indeed return "Empty Snapshot". Where on earth do I go from here?

Comment: Remove the `async` from the `getUsers` function, that will make it all run syncrounously.

Comment: Still nothing. I can see the querySnapshot but docs must be an empty array because `console.log(5)` is never called

Comment: I've added a snippet of the querySnapshot if that helps

Comment: I'm guessing it also has something to do with this message that I keep getting: `Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.` But I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Comment: This might be related, as you can see on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_65), this error indicates that you are using cached data (which is not filled since you never populated it) since the connection is failing. Try the solutions on this [community question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674482/firebase-firestore-firestore-5-0-4-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend) and let me know if it works.

Comment: Couldn't seem to get this working. I've swapped to pouchDB hosted from IBMCloud and it worked pretty much immediately. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Anytime, by the way, you might want add your solution as an answer to this questions, so that if someone in the community gets the same issue, they find your solution easily and also to include your reputation.